# Не работает localhost в MAMP на macOS

Tags: localhost, mamp

Закинул новые php и html файлы в htdocs. Запускаю сервер и нажимаю на сайте - Мой сайт. По идее должен быть список моих файлов, но нет. Страница абсолютно пустая и белая. Ничего не пишет. Подключаюсь в дефолтным портам Apache 8888. Все работало еще вчера, но сейчас нет.

Comment: А что со вчерашнего дня в системе изменилось?

Comment: Да вроде ничего такого глобального.